# laravel validation , store and upate uniques value , Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

i use laravel 8

i want to validate data and use one form request for store and update them.

i use `ignore($this->post->id)` for update unique data.

for update it worked, but when i want to store a new record, gives me error

`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

this is my StorePostRequest :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'=>['required'],
            'category_id'=>['required'],
            'title'=>['required','max:20' ,Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($this->post->id)],
            'body'=>['required'],
            'picture'=>['required'],
            'study_time'=>['required' ,'numeric' , 'max:'],
            'tags'=>['required'],
            'status'=>['required'],

        ];
    }

    public function message(){


        $message=[

            'user_id.required'=>'لطفا نام نویسنده نظر را وارد کنید',

            'category_id.required'=>'لطفا مجموعه مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید',

            'title.required'=>'لطفا عنوان را وارد کنید',

            'body.required'=>'لطفا توضیحات را وارد کنید',

            'picture.required'=>'لطفا تصویر را وارد کنید',

            'study_time.required'=>'لطفا زمان مطالعه را وارد کنید',

            'tags.required'=>'لطفا تگ را انتخاب کنید' ,

            'status.required'=>'لطفا وضعیت را انتخاب کنید',

        ];

        return array_merge(parent::messages(), $message);
    }
}
```

how can i fox it? tank you so much for your help :*

Comment: You should add more of the error. In what file is that error? Also you need to provide parts of that file that are relevant to line that is throwing error. Also what is `ignore($this->category->id)`? It's not PHP / Laravel function as far as I know. Is that use as method or something?

Comment: Please specify the place error occurs

Comment: @ShervinIvari hi shervin , the problem fixed but if you want to know ,this error occurs when I click on add or edit a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be  here

```
$this->post->id
```

so try this instead

```
$post->id
```

or That

```
$this->post['id']
```

I hope that works!

Comment: thank you so much ..`$post->id`  didn't work but `$this->post['id']`  worked ^_^

Comment: you're welcome :) 

could you please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
       $rules = [
            'user_id'=>['required'],
            'category_id'=>['required'],
            'body'=>['required'],
            'picture'=>['required'],
            'study_time'=>['required','numeric'],
            'tags'=>['required'],
            'status'=>['required'],
        ];

     if($this->method() == 'POST'){
       $rules['title'] = ['required','max:20', Rule::unique('posts')];
     }else{
       $rules['title'] = ['required','max:20' ,Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($this->post->id)];
     }

      return $rules;
 }
```

Comment: for update post , gave the same error , I think it's because of my edit form action : `<form  method="post" action="{{ route('post.update' , $post->id)}}">
            @method('PUT')`
how can i  fix it?